# Use maven local module in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I currently have the following setup:

parent-pom:

- has our common as dependency

service-pom:

- is child of parent-pom
- contains purge for common, so its always the newest

If I now import the modules in Intellij, the common dependency is used from .m2 folder. The problem is that I cant do refactoring across modules or add something inside a class, I don't have autocomplete.

I tried then changing the project structure. First I've added my local common module as dependency for the service and placed it over the .m2/repository dependency. That worked for autocompletion and refactoring, but can get confusing if I want to use the .m2/repository version.

But compiling and starting spring-boot with it don't works. I added a field to a class from common and referenced it in the service. And when I compiled it, it failed due to this field.

Then I read that I need to configure an artifact (containing common) and added a run configuration and enabled "resolve workspace artifacts". But that also did not work as expected.

Then I've added my local common module to the parent-pom module and added the parent-pom module to the service. In addition I've configured an artifact for the parent-pom.

But that didn't work either.

How can I compile and start my service with the local version of my common (and also be able to use the .m2 if needed)

Comment: Normally, I would change version in parent POM to something that fits, run `mvn clean install` in parent-POM project. Then I would refer to new version of parent POM in service-POM, and then you should be ready to go. BR

Comment: @RoarS. So I probably need a maven profile, because I need to deactivate purging. Otherwise it would delete my local version.

Answer (score 0):

How do you declare the dependencies between these modules in maven?

Do you have these modules imported into the same IDE project as Maven projects?

For IDE to resolve dependencies to the Maven modules with sources instead of the jars from the local repository, these requirements should be met:

- Those Maven modules with sources which you have on your local machine must be added to the same IDE project;
- The Maven coordinates (`groupId`, `artifactId`, `versionId`) of these dependencies must match to coordinates of maven modules with sources.

To be able to switch to a local .m2 dependency instead of modules, I think a Maven profile may be used indeed.

Comment: Yes they're imported in Intellij as a multi modul project. Also as maven via the pom.xml. I'm not sure what you mean with "How do you declare the dependencies between these modules in maven?" Can you explain further? The groupId, artifactId and versionId matches. If I install common locally it works (when purge is deactivated)