# Multiple modules in an IntelliJ project can’t access implementation of a class from different module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently in the process of moving from eclipse to IntelliJ, having a few issues with the project structure I understand the difference between how eclipse lays out a project (workspace, project, etc) and IntelliJ uses project as the workspace and modules as projects (intellij to eclipse reference)

A few issues have risen first when I have all my modules in my project and I try to find the implementation of a class in another module it seems to be directing me to the .m2 cached version and not the version of the class I have in my IntelliJ project.
As an example module A imports from module B, when I’m in module A and I hit “got to implementation” it builds the version in my .m2 not the class that is in module B

Secondly when I try to import a project(module) that houses all our
WSDL projects for some reason it greys out the imports in all the other modules that previously pointed to these WSDL projects in the .m2.

Is there a way to link all the modules?

I have already tried pulling in the other modules as dependencies in the project structure.
I have also set the correct jdk and maven build version.
Not sure if there is something glaring I might have missed but it’s taken up a few hours of my day already no just trying to get the project structure correct

Comment: Are you using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle? You should let IntelliJ derive its structure from their build scripts, it's much easier. No manual config needed.

Comment: Yeah I’m using maven, I have been letting maven derive the project structure but still it’s not working as expected , for reference in eclipse we had 6 different project and I could hit f3 on let’s say an object from another project that we used in a class and it would take me to that class in the other project in my workspace, is this something IntelliJ doesn’t do ?

Comment: Once everything resolves correctly, yes, that should work. I believe IntelliJ even has a keymap for Eclipse users, but by default it's Ctrl-B.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73566879/2000323